# visual studio code is missing in the installation of anaconda3

Tags: visual-studio-code, navigator, anaconda3

I need visual studio code installation as a component of anaconda3. I downloaded anaconda installer (02/2020 .exe file), but no visual studio code component in the installed anaconda3 navigator or in my PC. Does anybody know how I could make this missing component back in anaconda3 navigator?

Besides, I have also noticed that different anaconda3 NAVIGATOR packages are installed each time when I execute anaconda-2020-02 exe file. Is there a way I could selectively install anaconda packages in its navigator by myself?

Comment: The question and the answer are not matched for this posting. I would suggest that moderators delete it

Answer (score 0):

For that, there is a way to install VSCode once you have Anaconda installed. Check out this link: https://nathancarter.github.io/MA346-course-notes/_build/html/vs-code-installation.html

And regarding your other question, it would be good if your provided some examples of the packages that are installed. And yes, of course you can install them by yourself. You can do this by using the `conda` command in the console, for example:

```
conda install scipy
```

will install scipy.

For more information on how to manage packages in conda, check:

https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html

Comment: I completely understood your example. However, The packages I meant here is such as VS Code etc not shown up in the existing anaconda navigator. However, I have fixed this problem by installing a different version of anaconda installer.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with Visual Studio Code not appearing in Anaconda Navigator. Even after refreshing, it wasn't there. So, I decided to install VS Code separately. After the installation, I refreshed Anaconda Navigator again, and voila, the VS Code option appeared! If you're facing a similar problem, try installing VS Code outside of Anaconda Navigator and then refresh the Navigator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).